# Calculate value of Uniswap V3 position

Tags: uniswap, defi

The valuation of Uniswap V2 positions seems to be pretty straightforward through the subgraph. All I need to do is query a user's LP token balances, and then determine the price of each LP token, which is easily done via the data provided by the subgraph.

I am wondering how the same result can be achieved but for V3 positions, which also has a subgraph, but seems to be much more complex in its valuation process.